# Confusing INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE error integrating SAML identity provider with Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, saml

I am trying to integrate a SAML identity provider with Firebase as the SP, and am following instructions on https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/saml, using `SAMLAuthProvider` and `signInWithPopup`.

I get the popup, which redirects to my identity provider. I login there, the popup closes, but the POST to `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithIdp` returns an error:

```
    "code": 400,
    "message": "INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE : InResponseTo in both Response and SubjectConfirmationData must be absent for IdP-initiated flow.",
```

This error is confusing, as from my understanding I am using a SP-Initiated flow (the initial request is coming from Firebase, not from my IDP). Additionally, according to the Firebase docs, "Firebase Authentication supports only the service-provider initiated SAML flow.", so they don't support idp initiated flows.

Interestingly, if I remove the `InResponseTo` from the `Response` and `SubjectConfirmationData` elements coming from my IDP, I am able to complete the flow correctly (i.e. Firebase accepts the response, and returns the correct user).

That said, I do not want to remove those elements, as from my understanding they should be part of the response in a SP-initiated flow, and the code generating the response is shared, and works fine with other service providers.

Why am I getting this error from Firebase? And what are the ramifications of omitting `InResponseTo` from a SAML response in a SP-initiated flow?

Answer (score 0):

One of my SAMLkit users experienced this error. In their case this error occurred, because SAMLkit didn't pass the `RelayState` parameter value, passed by Firebase, back with the response. This meant Firebase couldn't associate the SAML response with a request, and falls back to assuming the response is IdP-initiated. This has since been fixed, resolving the error.

Perhaps you're also experiencing a missing `RelayState` parameter in the SAML response?